# Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int em database.php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, crud

estou tendo uns problemas muitos específicos enquanto trabalho no meu crud. eu criei no banco de dados um campo chamado id, do tipo INT e A_I e tento chamar ele por meio dessa parte do código, porém ele fica dando esse erro:
Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\inc\database.php on line 25

```
    $database = open_database();
    $found = null;

    try {
      if ($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE id = " . $id;
        $result = $database->query($sql);

        if ($result > 0) {
          $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }

      } else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
        $result = $database->query($sql);

        if ($result > 0) {´´´


já pesquisei p caramba porém não vejo oq está errado
```

Comment: `if ($result > 0)`, você está comparando um objeto `mysqli_result` com um inteiro; isso não faz sentido. Se quer verificar se retornou alguma linha, precisa utilizar o `num_rows`.

Comment: dá um `count` no `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

Mude seu código para esse abaixo:

```
$database = open_database();
$found = null;
if ($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE id= " . $id;
    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = array();
        while ($f = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $found[] = $f;
    }
}
```

**Nota:** O objeto **mysqli_result** não é do tipo **INT**, então modifiquei o código para pegar o **num_rows** que é do tipo **INT**, com esse valor você consegue validar seu bloco **if**.